# Нужна API для работы с майнкрафт, но с некоторыми условиями

Tags: minecraft

Вопрос довольно интересный. Делаю я один проект, не буду вдаваться в подробности, это лотерея.

В майнкрафте для каждого предмета, есть так называемый nbt-тег, например с помощью него можно менять название и описание предметов. Блин наверное придется написать подробнее. Напишу сначала поверхностно, а потом глубже.
Игроки скупают все билеты, в билетах по три поля, в каждом поле по 5 букв, дожидаются розыгрыша.
Когда проходит сам розыгрыш, я выставляю 15 рандомных букв и игроки проверяют, если все буквы в полях совпали, то приз, естественно чем больше таких совпавших полей, тем больше приз.

Такие билеты делать сложно, я использую nbt теги, но чтобы редактировать их в игре(я играю на игровом сервере) нужно иметь привилегию. Держишь предмет в руке прописываешь команду и билет меняется, но не сразу, все зависит от пинга и tps сервера, выяснилось позже, что у этого метода, кроме времени печати, есть один косяк - это подделывание билетов, поэтому надо было что то менять. Нашел мод для этого, он мог редактировать nbt теги так как они есть, и я встраивал туда еще и сгенерированный код. Вроде все ок, написал скрипт для этого всего(скрипт кстати тупо генерирует буквы, все это к nbt и использует программное нажатие клавиш - костыли), ок так ок, а билеты нужно продавать игрокам, на аукционе максимум 12 предметов на продажу можно разместить, билетов 200 и их продавать надо не менее 8 часов, хоть даже на сервера играет больше 250 человек. Решил думаю сохранять эти nbt теги и написать бота для того чтобы он сам за меня продавал, когда надо поставлял новый билет на аукцион и тому подобное. Плюсом мода является, еще то что на предмете изменяешь nbt не отправляя запрос на сервер и происходит это довольно быстро.

Главным косяком мода является, то что используется лишняя трата ресурсов пк на рендер графики, а она не нужна, вот я и ищу api для этого.

Главные условия: Редактировать nbt, Без рендера графики и самое главное, что это все должно работать на клиентской части, так как не имею физического доступа к серверу, так как ясно дело не мой.

Видел, что то подобное, но хз как подрубить

https://github.com/twoolie/NBT

https://github.com/natiiix/NbtEditor

https://github.com/mstefarov/fNbt

Скорее они мне не подходят, так как они для одиночной игры.
В принципе язык любой, лишь бы условиям удовлетворяли.

Вот скриншоты, хоть что может поняли.

Вот просто предмет без описание и т.д.(не стал заморачиваться с цветом текста)
https://ibb.co/W6g2MLv

Это я с модом написал команду, держа предмет в руке
.nbt add {code:"Это не видят обычные игроки",display:{Lore:["Описание","Вторая строка"],Name:"Название"}}

и вот, работает быстро в отличие от стандартной команды
https://ibb.co/2yH9sk3

Comment: в последнем тегу code можно дать любое название и сделать их хоть сколько

Comment: Хммм....а что Вы от нас хотите?

Comment: Сформулируйте четко свой вопрос...пока не особо понятно как вам можно помочь

Comment: Если вы не играли в игру, то для вас сложно объяснить её механику.

Comment: Я знаю форум "моддеров" для майнкрафта, но там тоже ничего хорошего